ExecDos plugin artifact id, group id, version
I need to upload the https://nsis.sourceforge.io/ExecDos_plug-in in our official nexus repository, is there any way I can find the artifact id, group id or version of this plugin.
I don't see anything on their official page.

This is not part of any project, it's just a free standing plug-in.
The best you can do is the history in execDos.c:

1.0.1.3  Dec 11 2014

